# Riak: are links dissolved if the target is deleted?

Tags: nosql, riak, broken-links

When an item is deleted from a store are links automatically deleted from all of the documents linking to the now missing item?  Or do we have a situation that's similar to a broken link on an HTML page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, links are not deleted automatically.

Links are just a metadata stored with objects so to find all objects which link to a deleted object you need to traverse the whole database which is not reasonable.

Comment: I guess that Riak cant answer "what links to this node" queries?

Comment: No. There is no any indexes for links in Riak.